# Shell Script: Need to use previous folder than current directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Having this structure:

> /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/my_script.sh

At one point in my script a need to store the complete path to dir3 into a variable.
I know this works:

```
CURRENT=`pwd`
```

But, How can I store the previous one?

WARNING: I have searched for similar questions, but all include changing the current directory, which is something i want to avoid.

Edit: What I mean is, as i'm running my_script.sh, the current directory is /dir1/dir2/dir3/**dir4/**
I want to store in a variable just: /dir1/dir2/**dir3/**

Comment: You mean like `$OLDPWD`?

Comment: Do you mean the parent directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `dirname` ?

```
dirname $(pwd)
/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

To store the value of one directory up in a variable :

```
 x=$(dirname $(pwd))
 echo $x
 /dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
That's the fastest way (better than engaging in string manipulation).

Comment: @Joster - I'm curious, why do you consider this solution better than string manipulation? I can think of multiple reasons why string manipulation would be better, but I'm coming up short in this direction. (Kudos to PS for a quick, accurate reply though!)

Comment: @ghoti Maybe in compiling time and efficiency string manipulation is better, i don't know. I knew I could achieve it with string manipulation (as you can do nearly anything relative to strings) but i was looking for clearer solution, something you could understand with naked eye, i.e. if you forget the syntax in the future

Answer (score 2):

You can use BASH string manipulation to get parent's parent directory path of any full path:

```
$> pwd
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
$> echo "${PWD%/[^/]*}"
/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

`%/[^/]*` removes last matching pattern `/*` from `$PWD` which is the current working directory.

Comment: Yes right corrected, I got the grand parent instead of parent.

Comment: also, since single `%` is being used, `echo "${PWD%*/*}"` works as well

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing any string manipulation or launching commands in a subshell, you can refer to the parent directory of any directory as `..` locally or if you can trust the `$PWD` variable, you can use `$PWD/..`.

Of course, this just lets you USE the parent directory, it doesn't give you the NAME of the parent directory.  For that, you already have a couple of usable alternatives. For one more, read on.

In bash, the `cd` builtin command has two options,  `-P` which tells `cd` to use the physical directory structure traversing the directory structure as it resolves symbolic links, and `-L` about which the man page says this:

```
                                   the -L option forces symbolic links
      to  be followed by resolving the link after processing instances
      of .. in dir.  If .. appears in dir, it is processed by removing
      the  immediately previous pathname component from dir, back to a
      slash or the beginning of dir.
```

So ... while you might be perfectly fine with the following:

```
parentdir="$(cd ..; pwd)"
```

You can therefore get the parent directory with:

```
parentdir="$(cd -L ..; pwd)"
```

Note that while this does involve a directory change, the change is effectively within a subshell (`$(...)`), so it doesn't affect your script.

Note that I say "effectively" because strictly speaking, `$(...)`, `cd` and `pwd` are all *built-in* to bash, so you're not actually spawning new shells.